# Fetching latest directory created in bash by piping output from find command

Tags: bash

I have a directory like this:

`A/B/C/D/data`. Inside this exists folders like, `202012`, `202013`, etc.
Now, I want to find all folders starting with `2020` inside `data` folder and then obtain the name of the one which was created most recently. So, I did this,

`find /A/B/C/D/data/ -name "2020*" -type d`. This gave me all folders starting with `2020`. Now, when I am piping the output of this to `ls -t | head -1` using the `|` operator, it simply returns the `data` folder. My expectation is that it should return the latest folder inside the `data` folder.

I am doing like this,
`find /A/B/C/D/data/ -name "2020*" -type d | ls -t | head -1`

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not good at find command but you can use this "ls -td -- ~/2020* | head -n 1"

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava That should work if the directory structure is flat, but I'm assuming from the way the question was asked that they might be arbitrarily deep.

Comment: @JohnDoe : It is pointless to pipe something into `ls`, because `ls` ignores standard input.

Comment: @JohnDoe : if either answer below was useful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting one or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shopt -s globstar # Enable **
ls -dFt /A/B/C/D/data/**/2020*
```

Note that this would also list files starting with 2020, not only directories. For this reason, I used the -F flag. This appends a `/` to each directory, so you can distinguish files and directories easier. If you are sure, that your directory entries don't contain newline characters or slashes, you can pipe the output to `| grep '/$'` and get only the directories.

If you need this for a quick inspection in an interactive shell, I would do a `ls -dFtr ....` to get them sorted in reverse order. This makes sure that the ones you are interested in, show up at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the output of `find` through `xargs` to give it as command line arguments to `ls`:

```
find /A/B/C/D/data/ -name "2020*" -type d | xargs ls -t -d | head -1
```